# Android Studio AVD not working despite having image on linux

Tags: android, linux

I downloaded a nexus 4 x86-x64 image on my x64 ubuntu i5 laptop. Here are the error lines:

> 6:22:45 PM EmptyThrowable: /home/youssef/Android/Sdk/tools/mksdcard:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> 6:26:22 PM EmptyThrowable: /home/youssef/Android/Sdk/tools/mksdcard:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. I tried to find fix and found on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409905/apt-get-error-loading-libgcc-s-so-1)
`apt-get install gcc-multilib`

This fix solved  this problem for me! [Here it is!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeM6n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Debian derivative

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386
```

to verify the libraries used by `mksdcard`

```
$ ldd /path/to/Android/Sdk/tools/mksdcard

linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77e4000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf779c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf75ed000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56629000)
```